# How to change WP Gutenberg's category components panel?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

In Gutenberg Editor, I try to modify the categories panel (the one on the right where I choose the categories my post will be placed into).
One should not be able to add a post to a category if that category has child-categories. As the categories are static, it'll be ok to use the category-id.

My idea was to use the `enqueue_block_editor_assets` and add some javascript to disable the checkbox via the ID of the element.
This does not work, the element could not be found :-(

This is my unfunctional code so far:

functions.php:

```php
function gutenberg_enqueue()
{
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'gutenberg-additions-script',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/gutenberg-additions.js',
        array(), true, true
    );
}
add_action('enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'gutenberg_enqueue', 999);
```

(I use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`, because I am in a child theme)

gutenberg-additions.js:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var cat1 = document.getElementById('editor-post-taxonomies-hierarchical-term-1');
    if (cat1 != null) {
        cat1.disabled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. There is an example about that in the [gutenberg github directory](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/4ebd53cba1042fded4362724b55bb4c252d61357/packages/editor/src/components/post-taxonomies/README.md). It is written in the old es5 syntax, but should easily be transferrable to esnext. It uses the `editor.PostTaxonomyType` filter to edit the taxonomies component.

```
var el = wp.element.createElement;

function customizeProductTypeSelector( OriginalComponent ) {
    return function( props ) {
        if ( props.slug === 'product-type' ) {
            return el(
                'div',
                {},
                'Product Type Selector'
            );
        } else {
            return el(
                OriginalComponent,
                props
            );
        }
    }
};

wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'editor.PostTaxonomyType',
    'my-custom-plugin',
    customizeProductTypeSelector
);
```

If you need more information, also read the comments on [this github issue](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/6533).